# In Python, how to chart customer transactions over time (see embedded image for example)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe of the format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': pd.Series(['00001', '00002', 
                             '00002', '00003', 
                             '00003']),
   'transaction_date': pd.Series(['1997-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                  '1997-01-12 00:00:00', 
                                  '1997-01-12 00:00:00', 
                                  '1997-01-02 00:00:00', 
                                  '1997-03-30 00:00:00'])
})
```

There are thousands of records in the dataset (I'm using the CDNOW dataset: http://brucehardie.com/datasets/).

I want to plot transactions in the following format:
https://i.gyazo.com/e32c46b5f038f48cbf812a7d18e8beb8.png

Where Y-axis contains customer IDs, the X axis is a time-line representing the full range of the data, and each x on a customer's line represents a purchase.

I'm clueless as to how to start creating this type of chart because I'm not even sure what its called.

Any help you can provide will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A toy example that you can start working on:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': ['00001', '00002', '00002', '00003', '00003'],
    'transaction_date': ['1997-01-01 00:00:00', 
                         '1997-01-12 00:00:00', 
                         '1997-01-12 00:00:00', 
                         '1997-01-02 00:00:00', 
                         '1997-03-30 00:00:00']
                  })

markers = ['x', 'o', '+'] 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    t = dt.datetime.strptime( row['transaction_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    x = (t - dt.datetime(1970,1,1) ).total_seconds()
    y = int(row['customer_id']) 
    plt.scatter(x,y, marker= markers[y-1],s=200)

plt.yticks( range(1,4) ) 
plt.show()
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Very useful! Do you know how to add a different marker-type for the first transaction per row?

Comment: Marked as solved, thanks! I can work with this to get the info I need.